# Parse rows MySQL query over multiple layers

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, row, fetch

I have a query where I fetch the rows from a MySQL database on fetchrow.php 
I have a config.php where they need to use these data in. How do I parse it through fetchrow.php to config.php and back?

config.php

```
$helloworld = "Hello ".$row['firstname'].""
```

fetchrow.php (config file is included at begin of php)

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 echo $helloworld
```

Comment: You cant. `$row` must already be present when including the config file for it to be usable in the config file. You need to re-think the way you are doing things as it sounds like you're putting output where you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you.

define in config.php

```
$helloworld = "Hello";
```

fetchrow.php

```
include('comfig.php');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo $helloworld." ". $row['firstname'];
```

Thank you